# How to use addEventListener on inputChanged of inline options

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

So inline options have this function called `inputChanged` that triggers when you do something.

Like for a example a file picker inline option: If you click on browse, it does this command:

```
function showPicker() {


          var filePicker = Cc["@mozilla.org/filepicker;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFilePicker);
          filePicker.init(window, this.getAttribute("title"),
                          this.type == "file" ? Ci.nsIFilePicker.modeOpen : Ci.nsIFilePicker.modeGetFolder);
          if (this.value) {
            try {
              let file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFile);
              file.initWithPath(this.value);
              filePicker.displayDirectory = this.type == "file" ? file.parent : file;
              if (this.type == "file") {
                filePicker.defaultString = file.leafName;
              }
            } catch (e) {}
          }
          if (filePicker.show() != Ci.nsIFilePicker.returnCancel) {
            this.value = filePicker.file.path;
            this.inputChanged();
          }


}
```

Notice the `this.inputChanged`.
You can see what this function is by getting the setting xul attribute and alerting the `inputChanged`.

`var setting = document.querySelector('setting[pref="extensions.ThrobberRestored.customImgIdle"]');`

Now we see that inputChanged is:

```
function inputChanged() {


          if (this.usePref && !this._updatingInput) {
            this.valueToPreference();
            this.fireEvent("oninputchanged");
          }


}
```

we see that `fireEvent` on mxr is: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/mozapps/extensions/content/setting.xml#106

```
59       <method name="fireEvent">
60         <parameter name="eventName"/>
61         <parameter name="funcStr"/>
62         <body>
63           <![CDATA[
64             let body = funcStr || this.getAttribute(eventName);
65             if (!body)
66               return;
67 
68             try {
69               let event = document.createEvent("Events");
70               event.initEvent(eventName, true, true);
71               let f = new Function("event", body);
72               f.call(this, event);
73             }
74             catch (e) {
75               Cu.reportError(e);
76             }
77           ]]>
78         </body>
79       </method>
```

So we see if we want to trigger the `oninputchanged` event, we have to `setAttribute` on the setting xul element. So like if you did `setting.setAttribute('oninputchanged', 'alert("hi"))'`, after doing file picker it will show this `alert`. But I want to `addEventListener` on this `setting` element for `oninputchanged`, is this not possible?

My side goal goal is to watch `setting.value` and do something when it changes. Like if the user does file picker and picks same file, then `setting.value` remains unchanged, its really changed to the same thing. It's not an attribute I'm seeing in dom inspector so i didnt test out mutation observer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want to addEventListener on this setting element for oninputchanged, is this not possible?

Not without patching the binding's `fireEvent` (or filing a bug and getting it fixed). The name of this method is misleading. It does not actually fire an event, it just creates one, creates an anonymous function from the `oninputchanged` attribute contents and calls that function. No `.dispatchEvent()` on any element in there.

*Edit* Of course, you could dispatch the event yourself from within your `oninputchanged` code.

```
this.dispatchEvent(event);
```

> My side goal goal is to watch setting.value

A [pref observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Preferences#Using_preference_observers) will only fire when the pref value actually changes...

[`.watch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) on the `value` property of the `<setting>` element might work...

A mutation observer won't work (or at least shouldn't) as mutation observers should not see mutations of anonymous nodes per design, and the `<label>` holding the value is anonymous.

There is no `value` attribute, BTW, only a `value` (JS) property.

Comment: Ah ok cool man thanks! I updated MDN with this `oninputchanged` thing. So much stuff not documented man, people need to share. :( I heard `.watch` is bad for performance isnt it? The reason I was shying away from using the pref watcher, is because based on that change I update some xul elements. Then I would have to create another observer to notify it with the xul document. Which isnt a bad idea i just wanted to take advantage of features they designed :( For now I did inline crap: https://github.com/Noitidart/Throbber-Restored/blob/37d70ffeba4e4e875ba42d8215600e749e97914f/bootstrap.js#L160

Comment: Oh also im not sure if i could inline `Services.obs.notifyObserver` from `oninputchanged`. But on more thoughts it's privelaged so Im sure they have some `notifyObserver` function there. Reason this way, is cuz if I do just pref watcher, then i have to 1) test if addont manager tab open (can have multi tabs open, windows etc) 2) is my addon document showing

Comment: Damn, I getting tired... See *Edit* (of course, you could `notifyObserver` instead or do something else, like call a function in the corresponding window directly).

Comment: Ahh dispatch event! Oh my gosh totally forgot about that, thanks man! You are tired you're typing like me, "I getting tired." haha cant edit comments man!